# This while loop causes my program to hang

Tags: c++, loops, data-structures, while-loop

I have a function that is causing my program to hang.  I have commented out the function and everything else runs just fine. The program gets to where the loop should end and it just waits for input. The `isBomb()` function is simply a getter and returns a true/false value. The function is part of a Minesweeper game. I am trying to figure out a way to figure out how many bombs are adjacent to the chosen cell. I could post the whole program, but it is around 250-350 lines. The makeNum method is a simple getter that sets the cell number equal to the value of the parameter.

```
void mazeDisplay::countBombAdj(int row, int col) {
    int counter = 0;
/*  for (int x = row - 1; x < row + 1; x++) {
        while ((x > - 1) && (x < 4)) {
            for (int y = col - 1; y < col + 1; y++) {
                while ((-1 < y) && (y < 4)) {
                    if (mazeCells[x][y].isBomb() == true)
                        counter += 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }*/

    mazeCells[row][col].makeNum(counter);
}
```

Comment: Should those be while loops or just if () {}

Comment: Maybe, what you want is an `if` instead of a `while`

Comment: why is everything commented out? Please post the code that has the problem not one that does not have it

Answer (score 5):

It's your line:

```
while ((x > - 1) && (x < 4))
```

`x` dosn't change and there aren't any `break`'s in that loop so the loop is infinite.

Similarly for:

```
while ((-1 < y) && (y < 4))
```

It looks like, as others have commented, that you what `if` statements, not (infinite) `while` loops:

```
void mazeDisplay::countBombAdj(int row, int col) {
    int counter = 0;
    for (int x = row - 1; x < row + 1; x++) {
        if ((x > - 1) && (x < 4)) {
            for (int y = col - 1; y < col + 1; y++) {
                if ((-1 < y) && (y < 4)) {
                    if (mazeCells[x][y].isBomb() == true)
                        counter += 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    mazeCells[row][col].makeNum(counter);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, how can I run through the array safely?  The idea is that I should be checking the cells around the choice cell.  But I have to keep it from trying to check cells that don't exist.  Should I use an if statement to check for the range instead of while?

Comment: Thank you, that did fix my problem.  I do have one more question.  So that loop checks for the bombs around itself just fine.  I want to have it "start the chain" where if there are no bombs then it checks the next cell.  I feel like a recursive function would be best here but I am confusing myself.  Am I on the right track here?

Comment: That should be a new question, but you probably want to avoid recursion and do it in a loop (with perhaps another inner loop if you need up/down with left/right). Also `return` your `counter` from `countBombAdj` so you can tell if and how many bombs there are.

Answer (score 0):

Once you've entered one of your while-loops, the condition will never become false and you're stuck in it forever.

Also, checking those conditions with `if` instead would lead you to only scan a three-by-three square, which is a very boring minesweeper game.
You need to check if you're inside the board, not within that small square.

I would loop over the appropriate range instead of skipping invalid cells:

```
for (int x = std::max(0, row-1); x < std::min(number_of_rows, row+2); x++)
{
    for (int y = std::max(0, col-1); y < std::min(number_of_cols, col+2); y++)
    {
        if (mazeCells[x][y].isBomb())
            counter += 1;
    }
}
```